# How to get text only from the email content ? Ruby on Rails - GMail for Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I am developing a Ruby on Rails website where I need to fetch emails from GMail. I am using [GMail for Ruby Gem](https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail). I can fetch subject, date, etc, and even the body, but, when I fetched the body, I got a full content of the email. I am not sure if there is another field that only contains text only, but I already tried `content`, `text`, and `mail` but none of them are working.

This is the [sample](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/814b1ddf13f1539008d4f4a42609ed35) of content when I used `body`. I am using GIST since it's very long.

Are there anyone that can help me for this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
Gmail.connect("username","password").inbox.emails.first.text_part.body.decoded
```

Also if you want to remove "\n" so can use **gsub** for it.

```
Gmail.connect("username","password").inbox.emails.first.text_part.body.decoded.gsub("\n", ' ').squeeze(' ')
```

If you want to do for all emails then you can do something like this

```
arr = []
Gmail.connect("username","password").inbox.emails.each do |email|
   arr << email.text_part.body.decoded.gsub("\n", ' ').squeeze(' ')
end
```

Comment: Thank you. But I parsed the `emails` like this `<% gmail.inbox.find(:unread).take(5).sort_by(&:date).reverse!.each do |email| %>`

Comment: But you must be getting still the raw HTML as well

Comment: When I tried your code, it's said that `undefined method `text_part' for "Thu, 30 Nov 2017 17:34:12 -0800":String`

Comment: Try this Gmail.connect("username","password").inbox.emails.first.text_part.body.decoded.gsub("\n", ' ').squeeze(' ')

Comment: It's working, but I still don't understand why when I parsed it, it become not working.

Comment: you may be trying to read unread messages which are already been read by you. So when you are running the code again it is giving you nil. That's is why text_part method is saying undefined